# How much a statement of purpose can help with PhD admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

If I can write a convincing Statement of purpose which conveys why I choose the PhD program and show that I am well-prepared for the field, will it save other parts of my application? I read somewhere said that SOP is not as important as GPA and test scores.

Comment: It depends on how serious your admissions evaluator is.  The not-serious ones will see your scores as most significant.

Comment: There's no magic formula for PhD admission.